# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException in Spring+Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-orm

I am using spring and Hibernate integration using mysql created a simple java project with a package and 3 class inside it ,and an application `context.xml` file ,and an `hbm.xml` for mapping,But the programming got crashed at runtime with `Exception` :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

This is the Employee.java file

```
public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(int id, String name, int salary) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    } 

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println(id + " " + name + " " + salary);
    }

}
```

This is the Test.java

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Resource r = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
    BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(r);

    EmployeeDao dao = (EmployeeDao) factory.getBean("d");

    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setId(114);
    e.setName("varun");
    e.setSalary(50000);

    dao.saveEmployee(e);

}}
```

This is the EmployeeDao.java

```
public class EmployeeDao {

HibernateTemplate template;

public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}  

public void saveEmployee(Employee e) {
    template.save(e);
}

public void updateEmployee(Employee e) {
    template.update(e);
}

public void deleteEmployee(Employee e) {
    template.delete(e);
}  

public Employee getById(int id) {
    Employee e = (Employee) template.get(Employee.class, id);
    return e;
}  

public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    list = template.loadAll(Employee.class);
    return list;
}}
```

This is the employee.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>  
<class name="com.javatpoint.Employee" table="emp555">  
    <id name="id">  
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
    </id>  
    <property name="name"></property>  
    <property name="salary"></property>  
</class>
```

This is the applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="****" />
</bean>


<bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

    <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
            <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
    </property>  

    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <props>  
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

        </props>  
    </property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="d" class="com.javatpoint.EmployeeDao">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
</bean>
```

Here is the stack trace :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>       creating bean with name 'd' defined in class path resource
>       [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'template'
>        while setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>       creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource
>       [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested
>        exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/JDBCException

Comment: show full error log

Comment: The error log states that he can't resolve the reference `template` and that he doesn not find the class `org/hibernate/JDBCException` It seems that your dependency system is messed up. Check the class names for `template` and `d`

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="d" class="com.javatpoint.EmployeeDao">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
</bean>
```

You have created a reference to `ref="template"` and the Spring could not find it.

**Check if all required dependencies are available.**
Here you should check `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate` `jar` is available.